# no puedo identificar el error

Tags: php

acudo a ustedes ya que estoy aprendiendo php al realizar mi crud y quere mostrar los datospara luego poder editarlos me presenta el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, el código y el error deben ir en formato de texto por favor. ;)

Comment: cuando lo colo asi me dice que no tiene un formato adecuado

Comment: Copia el código relevante, lo pegas como texto, explicas mejor qué es lo que pasa y verás que la pregunta va a ser aceptada

Comment: Saludos. Mira en https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php al inicio de cualquier PHP donde uses `SESSION` debe estar `session_start()`;

Comment: muchas gracias por la información voy a revisar

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que lo requieras al inicio de tu pagina debes de habilitar el uso de sesiones, ya que sino el proyecto no va a reconocer la variable de sesión que están utilizando.

Al inicio de tu código PHP deberías de implementar lo siguiente.

```
<php?
   session_start();
?>
```

Acá te dejo un poco de documentación que también te puede ser de ayuda.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Saludos

Comment: gracias, gracias voy a revisar la información que me compartes. gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Nada, simplemente me imprime el Echo pero sigue sin pasar el executr